# Object containing an object in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I'm a Java beginner learning from a book and I came across a question which requires a FuelGauge and Odometer class. Then it says, "every object of type Odometer should contain an object of type FuelGauge. How do I go about this? Here's what I have for Odometer:

```
public class Odometer {

public double mileage;
public double gallonsPerMile;

public Odometer() {
    mileage=0;

}

public Odometer(double miles) {
    this.mileage=miles;

}


public void mileagePlusOne() {
    mileage+=1;
}

}
```

I want to add something to the constructor but I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

To add a FuelGage to an odometer, just declare a variable inside the odometer class

```
private FuelGauge fuelGauge
```

The class file specifies a template on which an object is built on. By creating a new object `new Odometer()`, you instantiate a new instance of the class.

The variables declared inside the class are unique to the individual instance as long as they are not declared "static." For example, each instantiated odometer has its own mileage variable.

By declaring a new fuel gauge like I did above, each odometer will now have a fuel gauge. Each variable of the class should be declared private, to keep other classes from modifying its internal state. You should use public functions which modify the values instead (getters/setters)

```
public void setFuelGauge(fuelGauge) {
    this.fuelGauge = fuelGauge;
}

public FuelGauge getFuelGauge() {
    return fuelGauge;
}
```

In your constructor,  you can include `fuelGauge = new FuelGauge()`. You could also overload the constructor to accept a fuel gauge

```
public Odometer(Fuelgauge fuelGauge) {
    mileage = 0;
    this.fuelGauge = fuelGauge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have your variables `mileage` and `gallonspermile` you would add a variable `public FuelGauge gauge;`

Then in the constructor where you set `miles`, you set `guage = new FuelGuage();`

Answer (score 0):

It means

```
public class Odometer {

private FuelGauge fuelGauge;

public double mileage;
public double gallonsPerMile;

public Odometer() {
    mileage=0;
   this.fuelGauge = new FuelGauge();

}

public Odometer(double miles, FuelGuage fuelGauge) {
    this.mileage=miles;
    this.fuelGauge = fuelGauge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would update your class as follows:

```
public class Odometer {

public double mileage;
public double gallonsPerMile;
public FuelGauge gauge; // Add this to declare the instance of FuelGauge

public Odometer() {
    mileage=0;
    gauge = new FuelGauge(); // Instantiate gauge, which you can now use as wanted

}

public Odometer(double miles) {
    this.mileage=miles;

}


public void mileagePlusOne() {
    mileage+=1;
}

}
```